# Network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred. [firebase_auth/network-request-failed]

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, auth-token

One of my production user was having issues with [firebase_auth/network-request-failed] since yesterday. He is experiencing a long loading time on most of the API calls. Everything worked normally when he re-installed the app.

I think it has something to do with the Firebase Auth Token? I am using auth token from Firebase for my custom API calls.

[image: firebase_auth/network-request-failed]